# Sending TCP data to a client behind NAT

Tags: tcp, nat

I am working on a client/server program with one server (not behind NAT) and many clients that are using NAT. I need the server to be able to transfer files to the clients every so often, thus the server must be able to initiate TCP traffic when needed. I have already figured out how to do this with UDP by caching the clients' IPEndPoints and using them later.

Can anyone recommend some sample code or a project (with source) they have seen that can do this? There are lots of Chat or IM projects out there to learn from, but they generally use only UDP across NAT or only work on LANs without NAT being used. C++/C#/VB source with a solution would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: So you want your clients to be servers?

Comment: I just want the clients to be able to receive traffic initiated by the server. The same way that a chat server pushes messages out to clients as they occur.

Comment: Well the clients aren't clients unless they already have a connection to the server, so you just use that. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best options:

1. Clients polls periodically to discover if new files are available. Simplest option.  This may or may not scale depending on how many clients and how often they would need to poll.
2. All clients keep a persistent TCP connection to the server.  Server sends files to a specific client when ready.  Avoids the polling overhead of #1, but might have issues if the number of clients reaches into the thousands if you haven't designed your service to scale for the [C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html).
3. Clients connect to a notification server which is designed to handle many clients simultaneously connected. Client sends its notification server parameters to file transfer service and disconnects. When file server has a new file available, server sends notification through notification service to tell client to connect back for an awaiting file.  Client disconnects from file server after file transfer is done.